# How do I unlock user in mysql without execute sql query？

Tags: mysql, security, database-administration, unlock, authority

I have installed some production, there is mysql embedded instance in production. Installation is successful, but when I tried to connect mysql instannce, I got following error messages.

```
[root@MiWiFi-R3D-srv bin]# ./mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/msql.sock' (2)
[root@MiWiFi-R3D-srv bin]#
[root@MiWiFi-R3D-srv bin]#
```

I can sure mysql instance is running.

```
aam      13390     1  0 08:01 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /opt/SIU_MANAGER/mysq /bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/var/opt/SIU_MANAGER/mysql/my.cnf --pid-file=/var/opt/AAM/mysql/data/my.pid --ledir=/opt/AAM/mysql/bin --basedir=/opt/AAM/mysql --tmpdir=/var/opt/AAM/mysql/tmp/ --datadir=/var/opt/AAM/mysql/data --character-sets-dir=/opt/AAM/mysql/share/charsets/ --lc-messages-dir=/opt/AAM/mysql/share --lc-messages=en_US --user=bin
aam      13578 13390  0 08:01 ?        00:00:02 /opt/AAM/mysql/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/var/opt/AAM/mysql/my.cnf --basedir=/opt/AAM/mysql --datadir=/var/opt/AAM/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/opt/AAM/mysql/lib/plugin --tmpdir=/var/opt/AAM/mysql/tmp/ --character-sets-dir=/opt/AAM/mysql/share/charsets/ --lc-messages-dir=/opt/AAM/mysql/share --lc-messages=en_US --log-error=MiWiFi-R3D-srv.err --pid-file=/var/opt/AAM/mysql/data/my.pid
root     17786 11762  0 08:27 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

I did little research. Mysql offical solution is that execute sql in mysql, but if I can not connect sql
I can not execute any sql.

Mysql offical solution https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/account-locking.html

> When used with ALTER USER, these clauses specify the new locking state
> for an existing account. In the absence of either clause, the account
> locking state remains unchanged.

This is mysql version.

```
[root@MiWiFi-R3D-srv bin]# ./mysqladmin -V
./mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.7.25, for linux-glibc2.12 on x86_64
[root@MiWiFi-R3D-srv bin]#
```

How do I unlcok root user?
PS: I have root privillage of OS.

Thank you for answer me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, for some reason, your communication socket for MySQL is being created in `/tmp`, and is presumably being deleted by some process that periodically cleans up `/tmp`.

You can get it back by restarting the mysqld process through whatever means is appropriate to your system.

You should also move it out of `/tmp`, perhaps into `/var/run`.